# Multiple pagename WP Query

Tags: wp-query

I wonder if I can use `WP_Query()` with multiple slug like `p => array(1,2,3)`

I have tried using `pagename => array('accommodation','activities','restaurant')` but pagename expects a string and doesn't accept arrays.

---

How do I Query multiple page using the page slug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple *slugs*, you can use `post_name__in`:

```
new WP_Query( array(
  'post_name__in' => array( 'accommodation','activities','restaurant' ),
) );
```

For multiple *post IDs*, you can use `post__in`:

```
new WP_Query( array(
  'post__in' => array( 1, 2, 3 ),
) );
```

You can check the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) for more details.